# Win8.1 in-app purchases doesn't work

Tags: windows-runtime, in-app-purchase

My app in store, but when I call
Windows.Store.CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync() - error 0x801900cc

Only for ARM. On x64, x86 all work fine.